# How often and how much to prune avoc seedlings

Tags: pruning

Plants are 18 inches tall I want them to develop stronger trunks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Cut in half as some do to spur side shoots for a shorter plant. Otherwise put outside after danger of frost for thicker growth and Mother Nature.

Comment: @YosefBaskin comments are not for answering questions, why not make this an answer?

Comment: Please post a photo of your seedlings.  And confirm what plant it is instead of using an abbreviation.